# Dropdownlist populated from datasource - values are inaccessible from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu, datasource

I have an asp dropbox which I populate from database:

this is the aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl_last" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
```

and this is the cs:

```
  ddl_last.DataSource = eggsContext.Customers;
        ddl_last.DataValueField = "last_name";
        ddl_last.DataTextField = "last_name";
        ddl_last.DataBind();
```

When I try to get ddl_last.SelectedValue from the c# code I get nothing. infact ddl_last.Items count is 0! When I don't populate it from code, but write in the aspx

```
<asp:ListItem Text="example" />
```

everything works.

I can get the value from javascript by writing
document.getElementById('ddl_last').value;

But I was wondering what did microsoft screw up this time that this is not working from the code behind?

Comment: Can you confirm that your drop down list is in fact populated when you try to populate it in your code behind?

Comment: Please tell how you define `eggsContext.Customers`

Comment: @autumyst - all values appear on the page, from javascript I CAN access the new populated values, what other confirmation do you need? :)

Comment: The values from `eggsContext.Customers` appear in the dropdown, but are not retrievable on postback?

Comment: @Shredder - using entity framework - myEntities eggsContext;
        EggsContext = new myEntities();

Comment: @Shredder - even before postback they are not retrievable. I set a breakpoint on a button press and checked the values of the dropdown

Comment: by the time the button press event triggers, postback already occurs.

Comment: @autumyst - Ok, you led me to the answer.. when I changed in the <Page> the property EnableViewState to true it worked. But if I'd like to stick with viewstate disabled on page, and just add to the asp:DropDownList the following - EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled" it still doesn't work, can I enable viewstate only for specific controls?

Comment: you should be able to, however, I'd suggest trying to find a more graceful solution. I had an issue which I tried to resolve simply by changing the viewstate, however, it may cause you problems in the future when you expect a behaviour, but you aren't getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your issue in comment, I think this may help you resolve it:

> To disable view state for a page and to enable it for a specific control on the page, set the EnableViewState property of the page **and** the control to true, set the ViewStateMode property of the page to Disabled, and set the ViewStateMode property of the control to Enabled.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstatemode.aspx

Note also, with ViewState being disabled, you can still retrieve the *posted* value by

```
if (Request["ddl_last"] != null)
    val = Request["ddl_last"];
```

Comment: you ARE the king! @autumyst - thank you for helping in paving the way to the solution

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the issue it seems that when you try to access ddl_last.SelectedValue and ddl_last.Items count your ddl_last list has not been data bound. Make sure you are accessing those values after you have bound data