# How Can I Clear DataGrid Before Postback In Viewstate?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, datagrid

There is an asp.net(3.5) search page. On the page after gettin sql result, the page size is 30 MB. If i click again (different criteria or not dosen't matter) i am getting "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown." message.

I want to this, if i can clear DataGrid (or gridview) before (button click) postback may be page cannot get the error 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Disable the gridview's viewstate if you don't need it.   Various questions on SO relate to this, eg: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11106341/2181514

Comment: And/or limit the amount of results coming from the DB.

Comment: @freedomm-m, I increased the web.config limits. But did not solve the problem

Comment: @VDWWD, If DB does not have a limit restriction. If we do not want this solution.

Comment: @freedomm-m, I do not want to disabled viewstate. Because there are paging, sorting, grouping etc. events.